# Excel to SQL Case

Tags: sql, excel

I am trying to convert a really convoluted EXCEL sheet into SQL stored procedure. There is one last formula that is kicking my butt though:

```
=IF(AND (W4+H4<=0,IF(E4-H4-S4>0,E4-H4-S4,0)<=0) ,0, IF(W4+H4<IF(E4-H4-S4>0,E4-H4-S4,0) ,IF(W4+H4<0,0,W4+H4),IF (E4-H4-S4>0, IF(W4>H4,E4-S4,H4+AF4) ,H4)))
```

I have created the equations in SQL to sort out the following:

W4.value1

H4.value2

E4_H4_S4.value3

AF4.value4

(as those were already determined earlier in the stored procedure. So I just put them back in as Outer applies for this specific subquery)

However, I have no real idea how to read this Excel formula, and the person that wrote it was fired, so I can't go to her for help.

To me, it reads like this:

```
 =IF(AND (W4+H4<=0,IF(E4-H4-S4>0,E4-H4-S4,0)<=0),0, IF(W4+H4< (IF(E4-H4-S4>0 then E4-H4-S4 else 0) then (IF(W4+H4<0 then 0 else W4+H4) then (IF(E4-H4-S4>0, then (IF(W4>H4 then E4-S4 else H4+AF4) else H4)) )))))
```

However, I doubt this is correct, as I suck at EXCEL

Anyone able to help me decipher this?

Comment: Well good thing that person was fired because that is ridiculous.

Comment: Excel's `IF()` have a format of `IF(Try this thing, True action, False action)` the `AND()` function is like an if, but it has multiple values to be evaluated like `AND(1>0,2>0)` would result in True.

Comment: She was let go for an entirely different reason, but it was things like this that started the ball rolling. Honestly wish I could share the rest of the formula's I have dealt with in this series. When you tell Excel to "Calculate" the formula;s, you need to walk away for about 16 hours.

I am about 75% done with deciphering it all, and verifying it, and SQL takes about 2 minutes. Thats pre-optimization of the scripts involved. Right now I just want to make sure that my numbers match hers before I really fix it all.

Comment: This is redundant time and time again, do you know what you are trying to get out of it?  At this point it would be easier to start from scratch and recreate the formula yourself.

Comment: Its a comparison of monetary amounts.

Depending on the values, then we either 0 them out, or go back to another equation.

I despise this whole thing, and cannot wait to rip it apart and do it differently, but my former coworker had the entire accounting department here believing that only Excel could handle this. She repeatedly said that SQL was powerful enough to handle these sorts of equations, or generate this report.

Comment: Let your coworker know that I now despise them for that formula, but I attempted a conversion below that should work.

Comment: I am testing it all out now.

With how she left here, and her inability to find a new job, its become fairly obvious that most people now despise her.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot test this currently, but I think you want something like this:

```
CASE
WHEN W4+H4<=0 AND (CASE WHEN E4-H4-S4>0 THEN E4-H4-S4 ELSE 0 END)<=0 
THEN 0 
ELSE
WHEN W4+H4< (CASE WHEN E4-H4-S4>0 THEN E4-H4-S4 ELSE 0 END) 
THEN (CASE WHEN W4+H4<0 THEN 0 ELSE W4+H4 END) 
ELSE (CASE WHEN E4-H4-S4>0 THEN (CASE WHEN W4>H4 THEN E4-S4 ELSE H4+AF4 END) ELSE H4 END)
END
```

I really had no idea how to format this, but I believe everything should work as intended according to the ridiculous `IF()` function, of course substituting your converted values and so on.

EDIT:

This is a straight conversion from EXCEL to SQL so please for the love of programming fix this so 1. someone else can read it (i.e. what if you got fired and you left the next poor soul the same thing you got stuck with) and 2. get rid of the unnecessary checks.

Comment: If it wasn't for the nature of the data, I would gladly share the before and after. At this point, I figure I have about another week of deciphering, documenting, and coding, and then a few days to show the Accountants that SQL can indeed handle this.

After that I will start the refactoring to do it correctly.